# Using Python IDLE with Notebooks

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, idle, arcgis-notebook

I've written a script in Python IDLE and in Notebook, both accesed within ArcGIS Pro, v2.9.5, umbrella in Start. I was trying to add the code from the Notebook into the IDLE script and was getting errors which were due to different versions of python being used (which as you can imagine is maddening). How do I tell Pro to use the same version or know which version is being used?

Comment: Do you mean "due to different versions of [python] being used"? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589722/11434833) for a code snippet you can use to check which interpreter is being used.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.